# Removal of the tag "analytic-functions"

Tags: feature-request, tagging, tag-management, retagging

I have just noticed that the tag [analytic-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic-functions) is used by only 14 questions, while the tag [analyticity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analyticity) is used by 549 questions. The former tag is also poorly maintained (empty tag wiki). Furthermore, I don't understand what "analytic-functions" could convey that "analyticity" couldn't (maybe that the question is about functions, not manifolds? in this case, we should also create the tags "derivable-functions" and "continuous functions").

Wouldn't you consider appropriate to remove this tag and retag all the 14 questions associated to it with "analyticity"?

Comment: I'd say it's a candidate for a tag-merge.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, that is what I meant. Let's see what the others say.

Comment: I'd suggest posting this in the [tag management](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/tag-management-2016) thread, rather than a separate post.

Comment: Now posted here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/tag-management-2016/23032#23032

Comment: @T.Bongers I am not sure whether this is the best thing to do - since the post already existed (and already had some votes). In any case, I at least I linked the two posts to each other. (My general rule of thumb is that if it seems likely that the proposal will need longer discussion, then it is certainly better to post a separate question. As another users told me [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/4/8), there was a recent discussion on meta.SO asking to which extent such long thread are useful.)

Comment: In any case, my comments digressed from the topic of the original post. If we want to have some further discussion on this, let's continue [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/4/16).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Fair enough, when I made the comment I didn't expect that this suggestion would need too much discussion.